# How to extract the final word of a sentence

Tags: awk, sed

For a given text file I'd like to extract the final word in every sentence to a space-delimited text file. It would be acceptable to have a few errors for words like Mr. and Dr., so I don't need to try to achieve that level of precision.

I was thinking I could do this with Sed and Awk, but it's been too long since I've worked with them and I don't remember where to begin. Help?

(Output example: For the previous two paragraphs, I'd like to see this):

```
file Mr Dr precision begin Help
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  But .. Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking about the problem, even if you don't know how to write the code itself. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this regex:

```
([[:alpha:]]+)[.!?]
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/wP5yO1/1)

Grep can do this:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -o -E '([[:alpha:]]+)[.!?]'
file.
Mr.
Dr.
precision.
begin.
Help?
```

Then if you want only the words, a second time through:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -o -E '([[:alpha:]]+)[.!?]' | grep -o -E '[[:alpha:]]+'
file
Mr
Dr
precision
begin
Help
```

In awk, same regex:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '/[[:alpha:]]+[.!?]/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/[[:alpha:]]+[.!?]/) print $i}'
```

Perl, same regex, allows capture groups and maybe a little more direct syntax:

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -ne 'print "$1 " while /([[:alpha:]]+)[.!?]/g'
file Mr Dr precision begin Help
```

And with Perl, it is easier to [refine the regex](https://regex101.com/r/wP5yO1/2) to be more discriminating about the words captured:

```
echo "$txt" | perl -ne 'print "$1 " while /([[:alpha:]]+)(?=[.!?](?:(?:\s+[[:upper:]])|(?:\s*\z)))/g'
file precision begin Help
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried the various suggestions, but this was most useful and I learned the most from it. Perl really lets me discriminate!

Answer (score 2):

gawk:

```
$ gawk -v ORS=' ' -v RS='[.?!]' '{print $NF}' w.txt
file Mr Dr precision begin Help
```

(Note that plain awk does not support assigning a regular expression to `RS`.)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^[^.?!]*\b(\w+)[.?!]/\1\n/;/\n/!d;P;D' file
```

For one word per line or use paste for a single line so:

```
sed -r 's/^[^.?!]*\b(\w+)[.?!]/\1\n/;/\n/!d;P;D' file | paste -sd' '
```

For another solution just using sed:

```
sed -r 'H;$!d;x;s/\n//g;s/\b(\w+)[.?!]/\n\1\n/g;/\n/!d;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*)\n/ \1/g;s/.//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 " while /(\w+)[.!?]/g'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `\w` matches a "word character".
- `\w+` matches one or more word characters.
- `[.!?]` matches any of the sentence-end markers.
- `/g` stands for "globally" - it remembers where the last match occurred and tries to match after it.